# Preventing form submission onclick of button created with font awesome with a function call

Tags: php, jquery, html, font-awesome

I am trying to use jquery to delete a row from a table when a button is clicked. The row is dynamically generated when the user clicks a + submit button.

[image]

Right now, when the button is clicked the form gets submitted. I'm trying to stop that with a return false. (Not sure how to implement prevent default in onclick)

I have tried 2 pieces of code. When using the onlick = 'return false;' on the button tag, it works fine. When I try to add a function call with it, it continues to submit the form and I'm at a wits end with this.

Variation 1 that doesnt work:

```
$('#tbl').append(                              
   "<tr id='"+countCourses+"'>"+
   "<td><button onclick='return delete_row();' style='border: 0; background: none;'>"+                              
   "<i class='fa fa-minus-circle fa-lg' style='color:red' ></i></button></td>");

function delete_row(){
 alert('hello');
 return false;
};
```

Variation 2(also doesnt work):

```
$('#tbl').append(                              
   "<tr id='"+countCourses+"'>"+
   "<td><button onclick='return delete_row(); return false;' style='border: 0; background: none;'>"+                              
   "<i class='fa fa-minus-circle fa-lg' style='color:red' ></i></button></td>");

function delete_row(){
 alert('hello');
};
```

I also tried the return false in both places simultaneously but that doesn't work either. What am I doing wrong ?

Last Thing I tried was, this doesnt stop the submit either:

```
"<td><button class='remove' style='border: 0; background: none;'>"

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.remove').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('test');
    // var num = $(this).attr('value');
    // console.log(num);
    // $("#"+num).remove(); 

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use jQuery for this:

```js
(function($, document){
  $(document).ready(function($){
      var countCourses = 'course-1'; //ids shouldn't start with a number (for testing)
      $('#tbl').append(  
         "<tr id='"+countCourses+"'>"+
         "<td>"+
         "<button name='submit_delete' style='border: 0; background: none;'>"+                              
         "<i class='fa fa-minus-circle fa-lg' style='color:red' ></i>"+
         "</button>"+
         "</td>"+
         "<td>Foobar</td>"+ //for testing
         "</tr>" //for testing
      );

      
      $('#tbl').on('click', 'button[name="submit_delete"]', function(e){
            //return; //-- simply return before the remove action on some condition
            $(this).closest('tr').remove(); //find the closest parent tr to the button and remove it
      });
    });
})(jQuery, document);
```

```css
td{border:1px solid black;}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="tbl" >


</table>
```

I think the thing you were missing is `$(this).closest('tr')` - in the event handler `this` is the target of the event. So we can simply find the next parent row above this in the DOM and remove it.

`event.preventDefault();` will prevent the default action of whatever it is your preventing.  Since your already in the event handler it wont prevent your code in there from running there.

If you want to stop an actual form from submitting, both `e.preventDefault()` and `return false` will work from inside the event handler.

But, in your example:

```
 $('.remove').click(function(event)
```

You have a class `remove` that I don't see on the button, but even if it was there you would need to use Event Delegation, because it's a dynamically rendered element.  There is a good chance when you add a new row, your event is already bound and won't detect these new elements.  Therefor you have to bind to a parent element that is present in the actual source code.  Then you delegate it to the button as I did above.  This way it can pick up those events and pass them to the dynamic elements.

That said it's been a long time since I looked up the docs on how jQuery handle events, it must have been like v 1.6 or something back in 2011 or so, that may have changed in the "mean" time... lol ... but I know this way works, so I just do it like that for the last 8 years or so.  Well whenever they got rid of `live` anyway.

Cheers!

Comment: This actually works ! thanks ! using the table followed by the button name works. Not sure why using the class isnt working... Any ideas ?

Comment: As I mentioned `A` your button doesn't have that class in the question, and `B` its a dynamic element so you have to use Event Delegation/Propagation stuff...  Here is a link with more info https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

Comment: If you take mine and swap the name out for a class, it should basically work.  I don't like adding spurious classes to the DOM just for selection purposes.  It makes it harder later to tell what classes actually have real CSS attached to them.  In fact with the event delegation you don't even need the name just `button` if there is no other buttons. `$('#tbl').on('click', 'button', function(e){`  Because that will only pick  up events in `#tbl` anyway.  The main diffrence between this and what you have `$('button).click(funciton()` see how mine is actually bound to the table...